# What is the best way to create a sprite-animation in raylib?

Tags: c++, animation, timer, raylib

I'm unsure what method is the most effective for creating animations in `raylib`.

There are basically two options that come to mind:

> 1. I can update frames based on a frame delay.
> 2. I can update frames based on a timer.

The first method doesn't seem great since it is not FPS-independent. It might run just right on my computer and terribly slow or fast on another.

The second method involves tedious boilerplate code for a timer implementation.

On the raylib [example pages](https://www.raylib.com/examples.html), they extensively use a `framedelay`s all over the place and update it for a few frames. Even though this is such a basic question, it's not clear to me at all what the better option is. I didn't come across any good advice on that either. Is there any agreed upon consensus? As for what I would use it's probably the timer since it is not FPS-dependent. (The function `GetFrameTime()` computes the delta after the previous frame.

A simple Timer-implementation would look like this:

```
typedef struct {
    float Lifetime; 
} Timer;

void startTimer(Timer *timer, float Lifetime) {
    if (timer != nullptr && Lifetime > 0) {
        timer->Lifetime = Lifetime;
    }
}

void updateTimer(Timer *timer) {
    if (timer != nullptr && timer->Lifetime > 0) {
        timer->Lifetime -= GetFrameTime();
    }
}

bool timerFinished(Timer *timer) {
    if (timer != nullptr) {
        return timer->Lifetime <= 0;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I think that is pretty straightforward, but as I said.. It's not the prettiest thing in the world.

Answer (score -3):

So, you're eager to create a sprite animation in raylib? Awesome, let's break it down step by step.

First things first, get your spritesheet ready. This is the one big image containing all your animation frames. You might have a grid layout or some other arrangement – doesn't matter as long as it's all there.

Next up, you'll want to load your spritesheet using LoadTexture. Simple as this:

```
Texture2D spritesheet = LoadTexture("your_spritesheet.png");
```

Now, let's talk about your animation frames. You need to define them. Think of each frame as a little piece of your spritesheet. We'll use rectangles to specify which part of the spritesheet represents each frame. Create an array of rectangles to do this:

```
Rectangle frames[] = {
    { 0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight }, // Frame 1
    { frameWidth, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight }, // Frame 2
    // Add more frames as needed
};
```

Got that? Excellent.

Next, set up some variables to control your animation – currentFrame, frameRate, and frameTimer. The currentFrame keeps track of where you are in the animation, frameRate is the time each frame should display, and frameTimer helps manage the frame switch. Here's how you can set them up:

```
int currentFrame = 0;
float frameRate = 0.1f; // Time in seconds for each frame
float frameTimer = 0.0f; // Timer to control frame switching
```

Now, the fun part! In your game loop, you'll want to update the animation by changing the current frame based on time. It's like flipping through the frames of a flipbook. Here's a snippet to help you do that:

```
frameTimer += GetFrameTime();
if (frameTimer >= frameRate) {
    frameTimer = 0.0f;
    currentFrame++;
    if (currentFrame >= numFrames) {
        currentFrame = 0;
    }
```

Lastly, to see your animation in action, you've got to draw the current frame using DrawTextureRec. It's like showing a slide from your flipbook. Here's how you can do it:

`DrawTextureRec(spritesheet, frames[currentFrame], position, WHITE);` 
The position is where you want to put your sprite on the screen.

Don't forget to clean up after yourself. When you're done, unload your resources to prevent any memory leaks. Use UnloadTexture for your spritesheet.

That's the basic rundown of creating a sprite animation in raylib. Remember, you can take this and build upon it for your specific game needs. Enjoy animating!

Comment: I appreciate the time that was invested to create this answer. However, it's more of a tutorial of things I already know and doesn't get to the core of my question. I was in particular curious about Timer vs. Frame-delay, nothing else. (This has not been answered here). Furthermore, I wouldn't create an array of frames that one has to set manually. Modular arithmetic works better for that kind of thing just by plain iteration. I appreciate your suggestions anyhow.

Comment: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: The [AI](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) you used seems to have a [cheerful disposition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYsng5_5h3g&t=2m20s). How did you achieve that? [It isn't easy being a cop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdULDIFU0EY&t=29s).

Comment: *"[I don't think I can stand that robot much longer.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0yBf1JKTw8&list=PLO-wxIy9sHyZsh6B56YoiHYbf9IAQGo3c&index=6&t=2m37)"*

Comment: [A backup personality](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qa2vDmgiEaM&t=7m21s)?